# Font problems in PowerPoint following Maverick upgrade

Tags: macos, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

After upgrading to Maverick, my fonts on PowerPoint are corrupted. Instead of printing a single quote, my system prints a division sign, the Apple chancery font is gibberish, and so on.

I've got a Macbook Pro 2012, PowerPoint 2011 for Mac.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling the fonts, assuming you have a clean copy of them somewhere?

Comment: I don't have a clean copy.  What's weird is if I open an new ppt file the problem doesn't exist. If I copy and paste the old presentation in the new file, it shows up again.

Comment: Thats odd. Maybe the presentation itself is somehow corrupted? If the fonts and charecters work correctly in a new file, that might, at least partially, rule out an OS issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the problem. There are is an incompatibility between font book and the Arial font.

I took these steps:

1. Upgrade Microsoft Office to version 14.3.8
2. In spotlight, search for Font Book
3. Find (in all fonts) the Arial font, right click and "Remove Arial Family". Do not restart your computer.
4. Take a new Arial font pack (here) or go to your trash and move the font that you just removed to the desktop.
5. Re-install your font (double click).
6. In font book, select all fonts. Drag and drop the Arial family to the new version of Windows Office.